# PostMapping application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 NULL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, header, content-type

application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type work very well

but application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not work. return null value;

I tried send the request value from postman.
set key = body, value = "1234" all types such as form-data, raw, x-www.form

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public ModelAndView success(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String body, Header header) throws Exception{
log.debug("encodeData="+ body);
return null;
}
```

if I send string value through body, null return.

Comment: Show how are you making the request.  I thought `application/x-www-form` defaults to UTF-8

Comment: I set key = body, value ="1234" at x-www-form-urlencoded in postman.
I tried all form-data and raw, x-wwwform-urlencoded. 
it worked when application/x-www-form-urlencoded. but when I changed application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 then null.